# ¿Cómo renderizar imágenes de una lista y el tipo de background para la imagen en flutter?

Tags: flutter

Necesito que esto sea más optimizable que poner tres card con sus especificaciones. La `CircularCard`, está desarrollada en otro archivo. Me da error y no consigo arreglarlo. El error dice

> type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'ImageProvider'

La circularCard:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CardCircular extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardCircular({Key? key, required this.image, required this.color})
      : super(key: key);
  final image;
  final color;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 23),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            child: new Image(image: image),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

y aquí la página donde quiero hacer el `listview.builder` y renderizar las imágenes con su color de fondo

```
import 'package:challenge_flutter_nav_nuwe/src/configuration/app_styles.dart';
import 'package:challenge_flutter_nav_nuwe/src/widget/card-circular.dart';
import 'package:challenge_flutter_nav_nuwe/src/widget/navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final images = [
    {'image': 'assets/icon-nuwe.png', 'color': AppStyles.backgroundCard},
    {'image': 'assets/icon-github.png', 'color': AppStyles.backgroundCard},
    {'image': 'assets/icon-aws.png', 'color': Colors.white}
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppStyles.backgroundDark,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 60, horizontal: 20),
              width: 500,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: images.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, i) {
                  return CardCircular(
                    image: Image.asset(['image'][i]),
                    color: Color(images),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Puedes probar Image(image: AssetImage('image/path'));

Comment: Y está, lo solucioné poniendo los valores en un array, no en un objeto, por lo que hice dos listas una con las imágenes y otra con los colores. No se si es lo mejor pero me funcionó